# Ground with different power supply and microcontroller

Tags: microcontroller, ground-loop

I'am encountering problems of ground loops with the scheme presented in the attached figure. In particular, the analog output seems influenced by the analog input signal, since currents loops I believe.

How can I fix this problem? What are the correct electrical connections?
I absolutely need not coupling (influence) between AI1 and AO1.

[image]

Comment: Is your "PC USB" connected to earth or is it floating? (some notebook computers under some conditions).

Comment: Floating I guess, since it is powered only by internal battery. I add also that "power supply 5 volt" is floating, but "DC stabilized power supply 12V" should be connected to earth (I have to check...tomorrow).

Comment: If you are worried about differences in ground voltages, why are you using multiple power supplies.  And why the filters?  If sound quality is important it should be pointed out that using a generic processor board will almost always compromise sound quality.

Comment: I think you are right, I can solve the problem using only one power supply (for example 12 Volt) and supply 12 volt to "audio power amplifier" and by using voltage divider also supply the microcontroller and the microphone. The filters are necessary for antialiasing (from mic to microcontroller) and to remove DC offset from the board (output 0-3.3 volt) and the audio amplifier.

Comment: Plain voltage dividers can't be used for power supplies.  Feedback self adjusting voltage dividers are called "linear regulators".  Designing an audio system with a high degree of gain but low cross talk is a challenge perhaps beyond what can be achieved with a digital-ish eval board.  Try to get all of your mic gain accomplished before the signal reaches the EVB.

Comment: Which type of linear regulators can I used? Are there some circuit available for this task? But the only solution to avoid loops or reduce the problems is using the same supply? About the mic gain is already set to the maximum.

Comment: Maybe LM317 or similars?

Answer (score 0):

You have several ground loops.

1) from the 12 volt supply thru the GROUND wire to the STM board, then out the other GROUND wire thru the anti-aliasing filter to the microphone and on to the 5 volt supply and its AC power wiring (capacitive coupling between primary and secondary of the isolation transformer)

2) from the 12 volt supply thru the GROUND wire to the STM board, then along the USB cable to the PC USB

3) from the 5 volt supply thru the GROUND wire to the STM board, then along the USB cable to the PC USB

4) the wiring in the wall or in any power cords (the fields of the "hot" wire in the cord is only partly captured by the "return" wire), coupling onto any of your circuits thru the air, and then taking **all** possible paths back to your local 50/60 Hertz 10,000 watt power transformer

5) the presence of any black brick battery chargers, with fast edges in the brick's switching power supplies (200 volts in 200 nanoseconds) that couple thru the air onto any of your circuit and then take **all** possible paths back to the switching power supply

Comment: I understand there are many loops, I also discovered this problem practically. What is the solution to avoid the loops? Using the same power supply for all devices? Is it the only solution?

Comment: @MicheleM. Loops aren't a problem until they become a problem. So just having a loop isn't automatically a problem unless it causes one. In some setups it can't be avoided.

Answer (score 0):

> I am encountering problems of ground loops

Perhaps, but my guess is the opposite, that you suffer from poor grounding.

The noise is probably being conducted into your circuit via the 5 V supply. Since the 5 V supply is not directly grounded itself, it might be modeled as a 5 V source with a superimposed high impedance common mode noise source, like this.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fEI4aA.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

[I apologize giving the capacitor in this circuit the name Hi-Z, and for this slight digression. That is meant to indicate that the capacitor has a relatively high impedance. This modeled capacitance is, in many actual cases, a "Y-capacitor" or a "Y" rated capacitor, where "Y" is a safety rating for capacitors. However, even in the absence of an actual "Y" capacitor, there is often a parasitic capacitance that needs to be modeled, and is modeled here with the "Hi-Z" capacitor.]

If the node labeled 0VDCout were solidly grounded, it would drain away the noise current passing through the Hi-Z capacitance, and the +5VDCout node would be a clean +5 V to ground.

However, in your circuit, this noise current must travel a rather extended path to get to the 12 V DC Stabilized power supply ground.

> How can I fix this problem?

My suggestion, and it may be contradicted by others, is, unless the distances between your components is large, to add a direct connection from the 0 VDC of your 5 V supply, to the 0 V of your *grounded* 12 VDC stabilized power supply. Yes, it creates a ground loop, but it will shunt the noise from your 5 V supply **away from** the components that might be affected by that noise.

[Let the criticism begin. :-) ]